# Can LCAO be seen as superposition?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

In wave physics, when waves interact, the principle of superposition applies. It states that the displacement of the resultant wave is made up of the sum of the individual displacements of the interacting waves. This appears to be very similar to the expression of a molecular orbital $\psi$ as a sum of the different atomic orbitals $\psi_i$ with different weighted coefficients. Is there any overlap between the quantum chemical basis of LCAO and superposition of waves?

Comment: Wouldn't be just superposition implies weighing coff to be unity? Otherwise yes, interference of waves is surely at the core.